# How can I vlookup across rows with title rows as criteria in Excel/VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, match, vlookup, transpose

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wg8QZnUPSR-uXeWjiYC9XYBxEkWx576smnPTVFCmtxw/edit?usp=sharing)

Data:
[image: Data]

Output:
[image: Output]

Hello, please see attached sheet. I have sheets with financial data organized by an ID column and by date rows in titles.

On sheet 1, I want to specify a date range in sheet 1 cells B1 & D1 for which profit margin would be calculated. For example, given the images below, I need a formula in B3 of output that can sum the profit values from 2/1 to 2/6 (34).

Could anyone point me in the right direction as far as VBA or even some in sheet excel formulas? Appreciate any feedback

Comment: [`HLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-A3034EEC-B719-4BA3-BB65-E1AD662ED95F)?

Comment: `INDEX` `MATCH` `OFFSET` `INDIRECT` would be worth a read also.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, `HLOOKUP` should be enough as @cybernetic.nomad poitned out. But yeah, obviously doesn't hurt knowing those

Comment: No worries, I prefer the `INDEX(range,match,match)` method rather than lookups for flexibility.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I'm not too familiar with Hlookup; I see how it looks up a row value given a date as input, but how would i use it for a range of dates and range of row values? Ie. if the date range were 2/1 to 2/6, how would i sum the corresponding profit sheet rows to return (4+6+7+10+2+5) 34 in cell B3?

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55165465/edit) to include sample data (and not a link to it)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad included; I don't have the rep to post embedded images unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MATCH` to find the ID and Dates, and a series in `INDEX` 's to return the required range t o a `SUM`

```
=SUM( INDEX( Profit, IDRow, FromDateColumn) : INDEX( Profit, IDRow, ToDateColumn))
```

where `FromDateColumn`, `ToDateColumn` and `IDRow` are found with `MATCH`

```
=SUM(
 INDEX(Profit!$1:$1048576, MATCH($A$3,Profit!$A:$A,0), MATCH($B$1,Profit!$1:$1,0)) :
 INDEX(Profit!$1:$1048576, MATCH($A$3,Profit!$A:$A,0), MATCH($D$1,Profit!$1:$1,0)) )
```